# oracle procedure error PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol "END"

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I get the following error:

> 58/6     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of
>   the       following:
>
> begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
>    current cursor delete
>   exists prior

Anyone have any idea what I am missing?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VALIDATE_BI_JOB_COMPLETE_PROC AS

msg           SYS.XMLTYPE;
msg_props     DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
msg_id        RAW(16);
queue_options DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
rec_count     INTEGER;
/******************************************************************************
   NAME:         VALIDATE_BI_JOB_COMPLETE_PROC
 *******************************************************************************

BEGIN

INSERT INTO JOB_LOG
  (JOB_NAME, JOB_SEQUENCE, RUN_DATE, LINE_SEQ_NO, LOG_TXT)
VALUES
  ($$PLSQL_UNIT, 1, SYSDATE, 1, 'Job Started at ' || to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'));
COMMIT;

rec_count := 0;

   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rec_count
       FROM  SCHEDULED_JOBS
       WHERE JOB_NAME IN ('bi_get_transactional_data', 'bi_get_reference_data') AND
             CURRENTLY_PROCESSING_FLG = 'Y';

    IF rec_count > 0 THEN
      BEGIN
        DECLARE CURSOR email IS
        SELECT EMAIL_ID
          FROM ERROR_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION
         WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' AND
          SEVERITY_CD = 'ERROR';

         vFROM    VARCHAR2(30) := 'WORK_SYSTEM@XXX.COM';
         vTYPE    VARCHAR2(30) := 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii';
         msg_body VARCHAR2(4000) := 'BI jobs are still running, please investigate.
         bi_get_transactional_data, bi_get_reference_data)';

      crlf      CONSTANT VARCHAR2(2):= CHR(13) || CHR(10);

      FOR email_rec IN email
         LOOP
           utl_mail.send(vFROM, email_rec.EMAIL_ID, NULL, NULL, ora_database_name || ': ' , 
           msg_body, vTYPE, NULL);
         END LOOP;
    END;

 END IF;

INSERT INTO JOB_LOG
  (JOB_NAME, JOB_SEQUENCE, RUN_DATE, LINE_SEQ_NO, LOG_TXT)
VALUES
  ($$PLSQL_UNIT, 2, SYSDATE, 1, 'Job Ended at ' || to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')  || 
  '.  Records sent to JSSO: ' || rec_processed);
COMMIT;

 -- exception processing goes here

 EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
             LOG_ERROR(
                p_APP_ID       => 'ORACLE',
                p_SEVERITY_CD  => 'ERROR',
                p_ROUTINE_NAME => $$PLSQL_UNIT,
                p_BACKTRACE    => DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE,
                p_SQL_CODE     => SQLCODE,
                p_LOG_TXT      => SQLERRM,
                p_HOST_ID      => SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'host'),
                p_USER_ID      => SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'session_user'),
                p_SESSION_ID   => SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'sid'));

        INSERT INTO JOB_LOG
            (JOB_NAME, JOB_SEQUENCE, RUN_DATE, LINE_SEQ_NO, LOG_TXT)
         VALUES
            ($$PLSQL_UNIT, 2, SYSDATE, 1, 'Job ABENDED at ' || to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY 
            HH:MI:SS') || '.  Error condtion.');
COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Comment: Most of your procedure is commented out... you _don't_ appear to have a BEGIN...

Comment: sorry my mistake in posting this. The actual comment ends after the line of asteriks. I am not sure it is valid to have two being statments. Could that be my problem?

Comment: Alen - Thanks for your answer, actually I tried this before. The problem is the INSERT INTO JOB_LOG statement that follows this  is not recognized when I make the change you suggested. 70/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored                                          
73/148   PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must move your `BEGIN` from the 28 line to the line 41. Instead of this:

```
IF rec_count > 0 THEN
  BEGIN  <----------------------------------------- THIS IS WRONG
    DECLARE CURSOR email IS
    SELECT EMAIL_ID
      FROM ERROR_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION
     WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' AND
      SEVERITY_CD = 'ERROR';

     vFROM    VARCHAR2(30) := 'WORK_SYSTEM@XXX.COM';
     vTYPE    VARCHAR2(30) := 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii';
     msg_body VARCHAR2(4000) := 'BI jobs are still running, please investigate.
     bi_get_transactional_data, bi_get_reference_data)';

  crlf      CONSTANT VARCHAR2(2):= CHR(13) || CHR(10);

  FOR email_rec IN email
     LOOP
```

Write this:

```
IF rec_count > 0 THEN
    DECLARE CURSOR email IS
    SELECT EMAIL_ID
      FROM ERROR_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION
     WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' AND
      SEVERITY_CD = 'ERROR';

     vFROM    VARCHAR2(30) := 'WORK_SYSTEM@XXX.COM';
     vTYPE    VARCHAR2(30) := 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii';
     msg_body VARCHAR2(4000) := 'BI jobs are still running, please investigate.
     bi_get_transactional_data, bi_get_reference_data)';

  crlf      CONSTANT VARCHAR2(2):= CHR(13) || CHR(10);

  BEGIN  <-------------------------------------------- THIS IS OK

  FOR email_rec IN email
     LOOP
```

Comment: This answer is only correct because of your edit to the code in the question. The original code would have caused the same error. I've rolled back your edit. Please don't edit code in questions ask the OP to do it, see [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200336/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code).

Comment: Ben, thanks for the information. I edited the code because the comment at the top was not closed properly. I thought that was an error in copy-paste-ing the code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `END;` just before your `END IF;` which is causing the problem

So Oracle thinks the `IF` statement is not closed. Plus it will ignore all the code after the `END`!

Comment: Nope, that `END` is OK, as he has a `declare - begin - end` block in the `IF` block.

Comment: Alen - Thanks for your answer, actually I tried this before. The problem is the INSERT INTO JOB_LOG statement that follows this is not recognized when I make the change you suggested. 70/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 73/148 PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

```
IF rec_count > 0 THEN
  BEGIN
    DECLARE 
    CURSOR email IS
    SELECT EMAIL_ID
      FROM ERROR_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION
     WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' AND
      SEVERITY_CD = 'ERROR';

     vFROM    VARCHAR2(30) := 'WORK_SYSTEM@XXX.COM';
     vTYPE    VARCHAR2(30) := 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii';
     msg_body VARCHAR2(4000) := 'BI jobs are still running, please investigate.
     bi_get_transactional_data, bi_get_reference_data)';

  crlf      CONSTANT VARCHAR2(2):= CHR(13) || CHR(10);
  BEGIN
  FOR email_rec IN email
     LOOP
       utl_mail.send(vFROM, email_rec.EMAIL_ID, NULL, NULL, ora_database_name || ': ' , 
       msg_body, vTYPE, NULL);
     END LOOP;
  END;
END;

END IF;

--rest of the code
```

The problem was that, after the 'DECLARE' you need to add a 'BEGIN', and an 'END' following the 'END LOOP'. I hope you understood. Also that makes me wonder, do you need the 'BEGIN' you have added just above the 'DECLARE' there? Hope this solves it :)

Comment: Thanks Tom, but where do I add this code, between the END and END LOOP?

Comment: please check the edit...it usually works when we are having coding problems.

Comment: Still not executing the insert statment after the 1st END statment. Maybe I can't have multiple BEGIN/END statements in the procedure?

Comment: having multiple begin end statements is not at all a problem, I have seen that a lot, and in some complex stored procedures I have seen people put each select query from a large database within a seperate begin - exception - end block.. So that's not the problem here anyway. Let me check some more,..

Comment: Got it finally, hope this get you on the right track, give this a try...